# Pygame delta time jolt on start

Tags: python, pygame

I'm experimenting with delta time in pygame, but when I start my game, the delta time always jolts really high over the first two game loops. Here is my current code:

```
import sys

import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([32, 32])
        self.image.fill((255, 128, 0))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 20
        self.rect.y = 20

    def update(self, dt):
        self.rect.x += dt / 10

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y])

class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()

    def update(self, dt):
        self.player.update(dt)

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.player.draw(screen)

class Control():
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = GameState()

def main():
    pygame.init()

    fps = 60
    fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

    width, height = 640, 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

    control = Control()

    dt = fps

    while True:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        control.state.update(dt)

        control.state.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = fpsClock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it gives me this output:

```
0.016666666666666666          
515                           
16                            
16                            
17                            
17                            
16                            
16                            
17                            
16                            
16                            
16                            
17                            
17                            
16                            
17
```

I have tried changing the initial value of dt, but that does nothing. I think it has to do with my game's initializing taking too long. If so, how can I work around that?

Comment: Where in the code are you printing the tick length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the creation of the clock to right before the beginning of the first loop. Otherwise the first jitter you see is the measurement of your initialization code.

```
pygame.init()

fps = 60

width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

control = Control()

dt = fps
# start recording clock from here
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    control.state.update(dt)

    control.state.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = fpsClock.tick(fps)
```